# Account Contact Role Help

Tags: apex, accountcontactrole

I know that Account Contact Role is very limited in terms of functionality.  What is the best way to go about this.  When an Account Contact Role is set to Primary Contact, update the Contacts's status field to Open.  Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `AccountContactRole` object doesn't support triggers, you're rather limited in your solution set here.

One option would be a nightly scheduled Apex batch class to perform the updates. It would be a fairly simple build, but all code.

The other possibility that comes to mind, if you'd prefer to go the declarative route, would be to use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries in Scheduled mode. DLRS could populate a field on Contact with the count of Primary Contact ACRs. You could then use a workflow rule firing on the update of that field to set or unset the Status field appropriately.